# How to make a label that expands when hovering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

How can I make a label that has the name of the section **"expand"** from an SVG in a navbar when **hovering** with the cursor. To make things more clear:
[here's a sketch of the wanted effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcpkt.jpg)

```css
/*this class is inside the <polyline> tag*/
.hover {
  opacity: 0.5 !important;
}
.hover:hover {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
svg {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.scrollTo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.localScroll-1.4.0/jquery.localScroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="firstPage">
    <div id="navbar">
      <!--these are the SVGs wrapped into an <a> tag-->
      <a href="#firstPage" id="a">
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Livello_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 118.7 103.3" xml:space="preserve" enable-background="new 0 0 118.7 103.3">
          <style type="text/css">
            .st0 {
              fill: #FF3333;
            }
          </style>
          <polyline class="st0 hover" points="59.3 34.4 59.5 34.4 0.3 0 0.3 68.4 0.2 68.4 59.4 103.4 59.4 103.4 118.5 68.4 118.3 68.4 118.3 0 59.2 34.4 " />
        </svg>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[This is my code](https://jsbin.com/vosiniziwi/1/edit?html,output)

Any help would be great!

Comment: No code in the questions will be closed soon. Kindly add some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with CSS transitions.  See my code:

**CSS:**

```
    #container{
        width:180px;
        margin:0 auto;
        text-align:center;
    }

    svg {
      width: 50%;
    }
    a{
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    label{
        position:relative;
        left:-70px;
        top:-30px;
        color:#fff;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        background:red;
        transition: all 1s ease;
        z-index:-1;
    }

    svg:hover ~ label{
        left: -200px;
        transition: all 1s ease;
    }
```

As an addition, make sure you add the -webkit-, -moz-, and -o- prefixes to the transitions to make sure it is crossbrowser.

See the [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/pgaWbG) for your solution

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work any more when I put the <label> out of the <a> tag. I want to set the background color of the navbar to the same as the background so the labels become not visible behind the SVG. is that possible?.

Comment: The CSS specificity is written as svg:hover ~ label. If you move the label out, the specificity must change so it can reach the label. You didn't provide a label in your code so I put it where I thought it would made more sense.

Comment: @ashrafs. I updated the DEMO for a different specificity. Every time you change the HTML, the CSS will need to be updated. It's just how it works

Comment: @ashrafs. I would consider my first solution instead of the label out. The reason why is because if you put the label outside of the scope of the hyperlink, you lose its ability to link

Comment: The only problem is that I can't find a way to effectively hide the labels behind the SVG. If I position them with "px" units, it will not work with different screen resolutions.

Comment: You need to employ @media queries to allow for that. That would have to be asked separately in a different question

Comment: My pleasure. I dont mind helping you, but it's the way Stack Overflow works. This site attempts to help many not just the one who asks. So basically, you ask a question, someone answers it. You mark the answer with the checkmark and future users with the same problem can identify the right answer. If you have separate questions, it makes sense to asks separately, because it would be a different topic that benefits others people :)

Comment: I completely agree with you, I will check out @media queries and then if I can't figure it out, I will ask a question. I am new to "stackoverflow" and I was very surprised to get an answer so fast from you. Thanks :)